# Adding multiple shipping methods (supporting zones) to woocommerce site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For my clients site to integrate with a third party I need to create multiple shipping methods (flat rate) with unique names. I followed the woocommerce turorial to create a plugin to add a shipping zone and then found some instructions to make it support zones and it worked. I'm now trying to make the plugin create multiple shipping zones but although they seem to appear in zones - clicking on them doesn't add them to the zone.

[e.g. they appear here but don't do anything when clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX5zU.png)

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

function your_shipping_method_init() {
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WA_Metro_Shipping_Method' ) ) {
        class WA_Metro_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {
            /**
             * Constructor for your shipping class
             *
             * @access public
             * @return void
             */
            public function __construct( $instance_id = 0 ) {
                $this->id                 = 'wa_metro_flat'; // Id for your shipping method. Should be uunique.
                $this->method_title       = __( 'WA Metro Flat Rate' );  // Title shown in admin
                $this->method_description = __( 'Flat rate shipping for WA Metro Postcodes' ); // Description shown in admin

                $this->enabled            = "yes"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced enabled
                $this->title              = "WA Metro Flat Rate"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced.

                $this->instance_id = absint( $instance_id );

                $this->supports  = array(
                   'shipping-zones',
                    'instance-settings',
                    'instance-settings-modal',
                 );

                $this->init();
            }

            /**
             * Init your settings
             *
             * @access public
             * @return void
             */
            function init() {
                // Load the settings API
                $this->init_form_fields(); // This is part of the settings API. Override the method to add your own settings
                $this->init_settings(); // This is part of the settings API. Loads settings you previously init.

                // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
                add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
            }


            public function is_available( $package ){
                return true;
            }
            /**
             * calculate_shipping function.
             *
             * @access public
             * @param mixed $package
             * @return void
             */
            public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
                $rate = array(
                    'id' => $this->id,
                    'label' => $this->title,
                    'cost' => '8.59',
                    'calc_tax' => 'per_item'
                );

                // Register the rate
                $this->add_rate( $rate );
            }
        }
    }

    /***************************************************/

    if ( ! class_exists( 'WA_Regional_Shipping_Method' ) ) {
        class WA_Regional_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {
            /**
             * Constructor for your shipping class
             *
             * @access public
             * @return void
             */
            public function __construct( $instance_id = 0 ) {
                $this->id                 = 'vic_metro_flat'; // Id for your shipping method. Should be uunique.
                $this->method_title       = __( 'VIC Metro Flat Rate' );  // Title shown in admin
                $this->method_description = __( 'Flat rate shipping for VIC Metro Postcodes' ); // Description shown in admin

                $this->enabled            = "yes"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced enabled
                $this->title              = "VIC Metro Flat Rate"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced.

                $this->instance_id = absint( $instance_id );

                $this->supports  = array(
                   'shipping-zones',
                    'instance-settings',
                    'instance-settings-modal',
                 );

                $this->init();
            }

            /**
             * Init your settings
             *
             * @access public
             * @return void
             */
            function init() {
                // Load the settings API
                $this->init_form_fields(); // This is part of the settings API. Override the method to add your own settings
                $this->init_settings(); // This is part of the settings API. Loads settings you previously init.

                // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
                add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
            }

            public function is_available( $package ){
                return true;
            }

            /**
             * calculate_shipping function.
             *
             * @access public
             * @param mixed $package
             * @return void
             */
            public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
                $rate = array(
                    'id' => $this->id,
                    'label' => $this->title,
                    'cost' => '8.59',
                    'calc_tax' => 'per_item'
                );

                // Register the rate
                $this->add_rate( $rate );
            }
        }
    }



    /***************************************************/

    if ( ! class_exists( 'VIC_Metro_Shipping_Method' ) ) {
        class VIC_Metro_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {
            /**
             * Constructor for your shipping class
             *
             * @access public
             * @return void
             */
            public function __construct( $instance_id = 0 ) {
                $this->id                 = 'wa_regional_flat'; // Id for your shipping method. Should be uunique.
                $this->method_title       = __( 'WA Regional Flat Rate' );  // Title shown in admin
                $this->method_description = __( 'Flat rate shipping for WA Metro Postcodes' ); // Description shown in admin

                $this->enabled            = "yes"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced enabled
                $this->title              = "WA Regional Flat Rate"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced.

                $this->instance_id = absint( $instance_id );

                $this->supports  = array(
                   'shipping-zones',
                    'instance-settings',
                    'instance-settings-modal',
                 );

                $this->init();
            }

            /**
             * Init your settings
             *
             * @access public
             * @return void
             */
            function init() {
                // Load the settings API
                $this->init_form_fields(); // This is part of the settings API. Override the method to add your own settings
                $this->init_settings(); // This is part of the settings API. Loads settings you previously init.

                // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
                add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
            }

            /**
             * calculate_shipping function.
             *
             * @access public
             * @param mixed $package
             * @return void
             */
            public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {
                $rate = array(
                    'id' => $this->id,
                    'label' => $this->title,
                    'cost' => '18.57',
                    'calc_tax' => 'per_item'
                );

                // Register the rate
                $this->add_rate( $rate );
            }
        }
    }

    /***************************************************/
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'your_shipping_method_init' );

function add_your_shipping_method( $methods ) {
    $methods['your_shipping_method'] = 'WA_Metro_Shipping_Method';
    $methods['your_shipping_method_2'] = 'WA_Regional_Shipping_Method';
    $methods['your_shipping_method_3'] = 'VIC_Metro_Shipping_Method';
    return $methods;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_your_shipping_method' );
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out why it wasn't working after reading the comments on this blog post

https://wpruby.com/shipping-method-for-woocommerce-development-tutorial/

Basically where I was setting the id for the method

```
$this->id                 = 'wa_metro_flat';
```

I wasn't using the correct method name in this bit, I was using the function name

```
$methods['your_shipping_method'] = 'WA_Metro_Shipping_Method';
```

It should be

```
$methods['your_shipping_method'] = 'wa_metro_flat';
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot!

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't having this problem but your original code in the question helped me set up methods for zones!

Answer (score 3):

Actually it should be

```
$methods['wa_metro_flat'] = 'WA_Metro_Shipping_Method';
```